# How to stream mic data between flutter and platform?

Tags: android, plugins, flutter

I been trying to figure out how to stream mic data from the android to flutter. I found some example code on how to query mic in chucks but I do not know a way to get the data onto flutter.

https://github.com/bitplane/Microphone/blob/master/src/net/bitplane/android/microphone/MicrophoneService.java

I am not sure which classes to look in flutter

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/EventChannel/receiveBroadcastStream.html

I wonder if anyone can help me point to the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I been digging through example plugins in flutter github and found this.

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/sensors

Unfortunately for me, EventChannel documentation is sparse. I do not believe we can pass streams from flutter to the platform so I can replay whatever I recorded in a feedback loop.

> Event callback. Supports dual use: Producers of events to be sent to Flutter act as clients of this interface for sending events. Consumers of events sent from Flutter implement this interface for handling received events (the latter facility has not been implemented yet).

https://docs.flutter.io/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/EventChannel.EventSink.html

The process is similar to creating a methodchannel, but I need to create an onCancel and onListen in android. Within the onListen, I must create also listener that could receive events. If I want to create audio events, I must use setPositionNotificationPeriod(int) and OnRecordPositionUpdateListener(listener).

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/sensors/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/sensors/SensorsPlugin.java

On flutter I must create a broadcast stream event

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/sensors/lib/sensors.dart

I manage to write my own terrible plugin that is android only atm. If anyone needs it I wonder what permissive license I should add

https://github.com/hungrymonkey/mic_stream

Comment: I found it very useful to figure out that java `byte[]` will end up as `Uint8List` in dart. That caused me the most problems. Your example code of the mic_stream and https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#codec was very useful.